# Why does my sqlite3 database not decrease in size?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, paperclip

I was testing some destroy commands for a Rails app, and I wanted to make sure Paperclip was actually deleting the files associated with my model.

I ran the destroy command successfully, and I got successful destroy messages from Rails and Paperclip, so I know it's gone.

The puzzling thing to me is why the size of my database seems not to have been decreased, despite a 704 Kb image being removed.

According to `ls -lh`, my `development.sqlite3` file was 17K before destruction, and 17K after.

Why do I not see a reduction in size in my database file?

Comment: If you read your own question, you'll see something isn't right.

A 17k database containing a 704k image?

Paperclip stores the actual image in your public/uploads folder. Not in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the [SQLite FAQ](http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q12):

> #### (12) I deleted a lot of data but the database file did not get any smaller. Is this a bug?
>
> No. When you delete information from an SQLite database, the unused disk space is added to an internal "free-list" and is reused the next time you insert data. The disk space is not lost. But neither is it returned to the operating system.
>
> If you delete a lot of data and want to shrink the database file, run the VACUUM command. VACUUM will reconstruct the database from scratch. This will leave the database with an empty free-list and a file that is minimal in size. Note, however, that the VACUUM can take some time to run and it can use up to twice as much temporary disk space as the original file while it is running.
>
> An alternative to using the VACUUM command is auto-vacuum mode, enabled using the auto_vacuum pragma.

Answer (score 2):

The VACUUM command cleans the main database by copying its contents to a temporary database file and reloading the original database file from the copy. This eliminates free pages, aligns table data to be contiguous, and otherwise cleans up the database file structure.

When an object is dropped from the database, it leaves behind empty space. This empty space will be reused the next time new information is added to the database. But in the meantime, the database file might be larger than strictly necessary.

[Source](http://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html)